# Top vertical alignment in \multirow

Tags: multirow

By default `\multirow` places the text in the center for vertical alignment.

How can I achieve `top` alignment with `\multirow`?

Comment: I'd say the entire purpose of `\multirow` is to center its argument vertically. If you want the argument to be placed in a specific cell (e.g., the top-most cell, just place the material in that cell directly (and avoid the `\multirow` overhead). If, for some reason, you must continue to use `\multirow`, simply use `1` as the number of rows the material has to span.

Comment: Please give us an example where this would make sense.

Comment: You could use \raisebox, but you would need to either calculate or fudge the distance needed.

Comment: @Mico nice suggestion, i'll try now. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `multirow` package's main user macro is typically invoked as follows:

```
\multirow{<nrows>}{*}{<text>}
```

where `<nrows>` is an integer that states the number of rows that should be spanned and `<text>` is -- you guessed it -- the material that needs to be typeset. Note that the whole purpose of this macro is to *vertically center the material* across the number of rows indicated by `<nrows>`.

If you do *not* want to center the material vertically across several rows and, instead, place the material in the top row, you could either omit the `\multirow` machinery entirely and simply write

```
<text>
```

in the applicable cell or, if for some reason you simply must continue to use `\multirow`, write

```
\multirow{1}{*}{<text>}
```

in the applicable cell.

I would recommend the former method. Less code clutter, for sure.